# jQuery Carousel Plugin Similar and Lighter to WowSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, carousel

I've been looking to develop a carousel for my site.

I've found a few plugins but really like this on WowSlider: http://wowslider.com/slider-jquery-elegant-linear-demo.html

Does anyone know of any plugins that produce a similar output, i.e, linear smoothing, transparent next/prev buttons, and differing information popups on each image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try carouFredSel - http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

It's free, it supports the standard jQuery easing transitions, and it supports transparent next/prev buttons. It also supports callbacks so you could easily customize it to get different popups on each image.